# VBA: SEARCH for text within other text, return adjacent cell. Loop this

Tags: vba, excel

Im very new to VBA and have largely been learning from SO, recording macros and then joining bits of code together (with limited success).

In Excel I have a list of strings in one column lets call that B, I need to SEARCH for that string in A, which is another column of strings which could contain the string in B. So say we start off with B1, when it finds the row with B1 in it in A, it then returns the string in the row which it was found (from column C) (and Column D and E).

Essentially it's a VLOOKUP (or as I prefer INDEXMATCH) but instead of the lookup_value being exactly equal to a cell in the lookup_range, it SEARCHes for the lookup_value.

In excel formulae I can do it:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1), B1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B2),B2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B3),B3,.....

But it's impossible to fit it into a cell and I know it's just easier to do in VBA; I'm just not good enough in VBA.
Ideally, what would also then happen would this would then move to B2 and loop until it finds the first empty cell in B.

Current bad attempt:

```
Sub ATTEMPT()
  Dim x As String
  Dim found As Boolean
  ' Select first line of data.
  Range("A2").Select
  ' Set search variable value.
  x = Range("B929")
  ' Set Boolean variable "found" to false.
  found = False
  ' Set Do loop to stop at empty cell.
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
     If InStr(Range("A2:A1000").Value, "BA025") > 0 Then
        found = True
        Exit Do
     End If
     ' Step down 1 row from present location.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop  End Sub
```

I would be very grateful for any help.
Thanks.

Comment: take a look at [Sidhart Rout: .Find and .FindNext in VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) - that may give you some ideas

Comment: Thank you; I'll have a try with that